# How to do an inheritance mapping in Hibernate with a one-to-one relationship?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, inheritance, one-to-one

I've got two MySQL tables and want to map them with hibernate:

```
cars
- Id
- owner

audis:
- AudiId
- model
```

In the Code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cars")
public class Car{
    Integer id;
    String owner;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "audis")
public class Audi extends Car{
    String model;
}
```

I want to have a joined primary key between them, so that an audiId references to an Id in the cars table. Ids shall be auto incremented.

Example:

```
cars
id: 1 owner: "John"
id: 2 owner: "Jim"
id: 3 owner: "Jake"

audis
audiId: 1 model: "A8"
audiId: 3 model: "A6"
```

What is the best way to do this with hibernate? Which annotations do I have to add? Which code is missing (except for getters and setters)?

I find many tutorials on this topic very confusing, so I would appreciate any help.

Comment: In Hibernate, you have to pick one of three inheritance mapping strategies. From your description, I think the "joined subclass" strategy is the one you want: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#mapping-declaration-joinedsubclass

Answer (score 0):

Try the annotation `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)` for  class `Car`. Also you can  use `@Id @GeneratedValue` for `Id` member of `Car` class.

[Here](http://blog.v-s-f.co.uk/2010/12/inheritance-type-with-hibernate/) is an example of how to use inheritance with hibernate. Hope it helps.

Comment: How do I specify to use the column name "AudiId" for the Audi class then?

Comment: @ka2011r with `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)` you could do that. In that way, each class has its own table(that means there will be an Id in `audis` table also). But this mode has its drawbacks concerning polymorphism

Comment: @yohlulz Could you provide more details regarding drawbacks?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the annotation `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)` in your superclass (Car) and create an id attribute in your Car with **@Id** and mark it as **@GeneratedValue**.

Then, in your subclass you use **@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="car_id")** where the name must be the same name used at the id of your Car superclass.

The **@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn** annotation specifies a primary key column that is used as a foreign key to join to another table.

Here is a [very easy example](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-inheritance-table-per-subclass-annotation-xml-mapping/) to learn about it.

Comment: Is it possible to avoid join with each sub-class during query of parent type?